# не найден pydasm

Tags: python, python-2.x, pip

```
    $ python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 21 2016, 07:16:46) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pydasm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pydasm

    $ sudo pip install pydasm
Requirement already satisfied: pydasm in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydasm-1.5-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg

    $ sudo pip2 install pydasm
Collecting pydasm
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pydasm (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pydasm
```

Вот собственно в чем и  проблема. Не могу установить `pydasm` на python2.7

Comment: Использую ArchLinux

Comment: В [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=pydasm&submit=search) вообще нет пакета `pydasm` - в этом проблема. Вы можете установить данную библиотеку только из исходников, с помощью `setup.py`

Answer (score 1):

В линуксоподобных системах:

1. берете исходники [тут](https://github.com/jtpereyda/libdasm/tree/master/pydasm)
2. переходите в папку, куда их скачали
3. запускаете `$ python setup.py build_ext`
4. запускаете `$ sudo python setup.py install`
5. пробуете импортировать

Для Windows можно посмотреть [тут](https://github.com/axcheron/pydasm)